# SqlCommand asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i you please help me out with my problem i am trying to create a function that output the data on a dropdownlist an setting my parameters my code goes as follow :

```
        public static List<string> GetTracks(out List<string> trackIds, string conferenceId)
    {

        var res = new List<string>();
        trackIds = new List<string>();
        var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Track_name,Track_ID from TrackCommittee where Conference_id= @conferenceId", sqlCon);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@conferenceId", conferenceId));



        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
       while (sdr.Read())
       {
        res.Add(sdr.GetString(sdr.GetOrdinal("Track_name")));
        trackIds.Add(sdr.GetInt32(sdr.GetOrdinal("Track_ID")).ToString());
       }
               }


        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        return res;
    }
```

thanking you in advance

Comment: It's more important that you have a using block around your SqlConnection than it is for your SqlDataReader

Comment: And your problem is what exactly?

Comment: I would guess the problem is that there's nothing in the DataSet... Is there?

Comment: i have change my code looking like this but i still have an error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'all' to data type int.

Comment: Yes, SQL will thrwu an exception when you pass in `all` for an `int` type`Track_ID`. Change the fucntion to accept an `int` for conferenceId, not a string. Then fix your code to handle the 'all' cae separately, trhough a different query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-write the entire function like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<ListItem> GetTracks(string conferenceId)
{
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select Track_name,Track_ID from TrackCommittee where Conference_id= @conferenceId", sqlCon))
    {

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@conferenceId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = conferenceId;
        sqlCon.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                yield return new ListItem(sdr[0].ToString(), sdr[1].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

And update your calling code like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(os.SelectedValue)) 
{
    os.Items.AddRange(GetTracks("all").ToArray());
}
```

And for better separation of presention and data tiers, I would modify GetTracks to return KeyValuePairs and the calling to add a select projection from KeyValuePair to ListItem.

Comment: with that code i can not calling it from my load page it do not work if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(os.SelectedValue))
            {
                List<string> IDs;
                var names = GetTracks(out IDs, "all");
                for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Count; i++)
                {
                    os.Items.Add(names[i]);
                    os.Items[i].Value = IDs[i];
                }
            }

Comment: @emilios - I didn't notice you had two columns there.  Updated my answer to reflect that and to show how to use the code.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually touch the result set `sdr`:

```
 using (var sqlCon  = new SqlConnection(...))
 { 
    sqlCon.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("...", sqlCon)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@conferenceId", conferenceId));
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                res.Add(sdr[0]);
                trackIds.Add (srd[1]);
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the purpose of your DataSet here. This is the sort of syntax I've used in the past. (I think the Syntax is correct - I don't have my code here)

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (sdr.Read())
  {
    res.Add(sdr.GetString(sdr.GetOrdinal("Track_name")));
    trackIds.Add(sdr.GetInt32(sdr.GetOrdinal("Track_ID")).ToString())
  }
}
```

EDIT: and as stated in the comments, put a using around the SqlConnection to save you Closing / Disposing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be doing anything with your SqlDataReader.  Typically you would have something like this:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(sdr.Read())
   {
      //whatever
   }
...
```

Right now it looks like you are executing the command and then doing nothing with the results.  I'm not sure how the DataTable comes into play either.